# Fail to connect to MongoDB via HibernateOGM using sessionFactory

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernate-ogm

I am developing an application that uses Hibernate OGM to work with MongoDB. sessionFactory is used to connect, encountered an error while configuring. Log:

```
...
2020-12-21 11:09:06 INFO  DatastoreProviderInitiator:51 - OGM000016: NoSQL Datastore provider: org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.impl.MongoDBDatastoreProvider
2020-12-21 11:09:06 ERROR HibernateDataProvider:108 - org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: OGM000072: Unable to configure datastore provider
```

Class HibernateUtil to get sessionFactory:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.ogm.cfg.OgmConfiguration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            Configuration configuration = new OgmConfiguration();
            //assuming the default mongodb settings
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider",
                    "MONGODB");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host",
                    "127.0.0.1");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port",
                    "27017");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database",
                    "test");
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.ogm.datastore.create__database",
                    "true");
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `hibernate-ogm-mongodb`dependency: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.ogm/hibernate-ogm-mongodb